# How to convert a sysdate month value to number in oracle?

Tags: sql, oracle

Im trying to return the CARDS of my CARD table that will expire in the next month. But the problem is that the table has two columns to represent the card date. The columns are EXPIREDAY and EXPIREMONTH ,both are numbers. So when i do that query i get an error:

```
   select * from CARD WHERE EXPIREDAY <= sysdate - interval '2' DAY;
   //Oracle error: ORA-00932: inconsistent datatypes: expected NUMBER got DATE
```

Is there a way to convert the `sysdate - interval '2' DAY` as Number data type?

Thanks!

Comment: Why would you hold the day and month in separate columns, and do you also have a year column? Your 2-day interval adjustment doesn't seem to correspond with what you said you're trying to do - look for 'dates' in the next month? Is 'the next month' any time in October, or between now and October 22nd?

Comment: @AlexPoole the database is of a thirdy so i have no control of it. And the 2 day interval is just a example, you could put everything you want in that query.

Answer (score 2):

If you want to compare the values as strings you can use this to convert the SYSDATE

```
SELECT TO_CHAR(sysdate, 'MM') || TO_CHAR(sysdate, 'DD') MONTH_NUM FROM DUAL
-- gives you "0922"
```

and this for your numeric columns which will pad with leading zeros if you only have a single digit

```
SELECT TO_CHAR(9, 'FM00') || TO_CHAR(22, 'FM00') MONTH_NUM FROM DUAL
-- also gives you "0922"
```

If you have control over the table schema it would be best practise to store both the DAY and MONTH values in a single numeric field, so that 9-SEP would be stored in this column as the numeric value `0922` where the month is first so that the natural ordering is used.

Answer (score 2):

A simple and not necessarily very efficient approach is to convert the day and month values into an actual date, using `to_date()`, and then compare that with your target date range:

```
select * from card
where to_date(lpad(expireday, 2, '0')
  ||'/'|| lpad(expiremonth, 2, '0'), 'DD/MM')
between sysdate and add_months(sysdate, 1);
```

[Which appears to work](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/117ad/1). But this will have problems if the dates span the end of the year. Because your table doesn't specify the year, you either have to work one out, or allow `to_date` to default it to the current year. And if you let it default then it won't work. For example, if you have values for December and January in your table, and run this query in December, then the January dates will be seen as January 2014, and won't be counted as being in the next month. So you'll need to do more to pick the right year.

This treats any month numbers before the current one as being *next* year, which may be good enough for you as you only have a one-month window:

```
select * from card
where to_date(lpad(expireday, 2, '0')
  ||'/'|| lpad(expiremonth, 2, '0')
  ||'/'|| (extract(year from sysdate) +
    case when expiremonth < extract(month from sysdate) then 1 else 0 end),
    'DD/MM/YYYY')
between sysdate and add_months(sysdate, 1);
```

[SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/0d620/1) using a date range from December to January.

And you can see the ways the two columns are being combined to form a date [in this Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/0d620/2).

As so often, the moral is... store things as the right data type. Store dates as dates, not as string or numbers.

Answer (score 2):

> *Im trying to return the CARDS of my CARD table that will expire in the next month. But the problem is that the table has two columns to represent the card date.*

Assuming:

1. you are using floating months (say: from 23 dec. to 23 jan.) and
2. your table somehow only contains one (floating ?) year of data

Why can't you use simple arithmetics? Like that:

```
-- some constant definitions for testing purpose
with cst as (
  select EXTRACT(DAY from TO_DATE('23/12','DD/MM')) as theDay,
         EXTRACT(MONTH from TO_DATE('23/12','DD/MM')) as theMonth
  from dual)

-- the actual query
select card.* from card,cst 
  where (expiremonth = theMonth AND expireday > theDay)
     or (expiremonth = 1+MOD(theMonth,12) AND expireday <= theDay);
  --                   ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  --            map [01 .. 12] to [02 .. 12, 01] (i.e.: next month)
```

This will simply select all "pseudo-dates" from tomorrow to the end of the month, as well as any one  before (and including) the current day# next month.

See [this example](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/0d620/13).

---

For something a little bit more generic, but *probably* more efficient than converting all your values `TO_DATE`, you might want to try that:

```
-- the calendar is the key part of the query (see below)
with calendar as (
  select extract(month from sysdate + level) as theMonth,
         extract(day from sysdate + level) as theDay
    from DUAL connect by ROWNUM <= 8)
--                                 ^
--              adjust to the right number of days you are looking for
select card.* from card join calendar
  on expiremonth = theMonth and expireDay = theDay
```

The idea here is to simply build a calendar with all the upcoming days and then join your data table on that calendar. See an [example here](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/0d620/22).

Answer (score 1):

Try using `to_char(sysdate - interval '2' DAY,'ddmmyyyy')` to convert  to character type. The date format('ddmmyyyy') will depend of the value of `expiredate`

Comment: thanks. Ive made it. But, is there a way to me to test this function to_char(sysdate - interval '2' DAY,'ddmmyyyy') outside of the query? just to see the result that it returns to me?

Comment: sorry, i don't understand the "outside of the query" part. Do you mean plsql?

Comment: @Aramillo - do you mean: `select to_char(sysdate - interval '2' DAY,'ddmmyyyy') from dual;` ? If you plan to compare as strings then it's going to be easier to use format `yyyymmdd`, and combine the two columns in the same format - with the same issue over picking the most appropriate year.